# White Space not going away bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, accordion

Under the headings in the following code snippet, there is some whitespace that will not go away. There is no margin-bottom or any other padding on the surrounding elements and I am confused as to why it exists.

**The Code:** Note: You have to click full page to see the whitespace

```js
$('#explanation').click(function () {
    // Make show/hide explanation text change on click
    if ($("#explanation").text() == "Show Explanation ▼") {
      $("#explanation").text("Hide Explanation ▲");
      $("#info").collapse("show");
    } else if ($("#explanation").text() == "Hide Explanation ▲") {
      $("#explanation").text("Show Explanation ▼");
      $("#info").collapse("hide");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<br>
<br>
<div class="row hideWhenDone mx-auto" style="width: 80%;">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8" id="excontainer" style="border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;border-radius: 5px;padding: 10px;">
    <h5 style="display: inline;" id="correctTxt">Correct!</h5>
    <a style="color: #007bff; float: right;cursor: pointer;" id="explanation">Show Explanation ▼</a>
    <h6 id="flag" style="padding-right: 175px;padding-top: 2px;float: right;cursor: pointer;">Flag Question ⚐</h6>
    <div id="info" class="collapse">
      <br id="seperator">
      <p id="explanation-text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed condimentum ante. Phasellus blandit, magna eu dignissim tristique, lectus sem scelerisque enim, ac sollicitudin mauris sem quis tortor. Aenean vel ornare massa. Aenean velit nisi, consectetur ut sollicitudin tempor, aliquam a nulla. Vestibulum condimentum posuere sapien sit amet tincidunt. Maecenas hendrerit condimentum venenatis. Sed lacinia lacinia vulputate.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4" style="text-align: center;padding: 10px;">
    <button id="nxtQ" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;"><h5 id="btnText" style="font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;width: 200px;padding-top: 0px;">Next Question</h5></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate any help.

**Thank you for your time**

Comment: Which whitespace are you talking about?

Comment: do you mean the padding around the box ?

Comment: `_reboot.scss` contains `p { margin-bottom: $paragraph-margin-bottom; }` which causes the extra margin at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by your `flex` display on the columns, so they're always an equal height. Notice if you change the `padding: 10px` to `padding: 0` on the second column (the one that contains the button) the first column will shrink vertically, removing the "white space".

So you either need to reduce your button/button column size, or vertically center the flex items

Comment: So can I just remove the class of row from the div?

Answer (score 1):

Apply below style to your paragraph tag white space will removed,

```
 p{
    word-break: break-all;
  }
```